# How can I get access to Google Cloud Storage using an access and a secret key

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have access and a secret key to Google Cloud Storage and I want to instantiate a client using those credentials. I've been looking at tutorials and came across this example:

```
public class QuickstartSample {
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
// Instantiates a client
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
/* Perform some bucket action */
 }
}
```

Is there any way I could pass that `access` and `secret` key while instantiating a client, in a fashion similar to that of `AWS` and `Minio`, something like this:

```
minioClient = new MinioClient("server URL", "accessKey",
      "secretKey");
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: I don't now if it applies to the Java client, but I found that over in JavaScript land, the official SDK does not support this method of authentication.  So, I'd assume its fairly consistent for other platforms as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication), "you don't need to explicitly specify your credentials in code when using a Google Cloud Client Library".

There are though some other options to authenticate you client in your code, but none of them use access and secret key as it happens in AWS buckets, for instance. [Here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java#authentication) you have a number of options to implement that authentication in your code, such as using the JSON service account key within your code or using an OAuth2 access token.

Comment: I followed the links you provided, downloaded a `Key.json` file from IAM & ADMIN page and it was pretty much straightforward after that. Thanks a lot again for clarifying this out.