# Use access and private keys to access google cloud storage java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

I have an application in which I am trying to read and write to Google cloud.

The documentation way of doing that is [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) and it works fine.

But I was trying to access it in a more `aws s3` way i.e. using access and private keys. 
While looking for ways of how to do that, I came across [this](https://bitmovin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001017393-How-can-I-create-Access-Secret-keys-for-Google-Cloud-Storage-) article on how to generate the key pair and I was able to generate the key pair.

Now `import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials` doesn't provide a method where you can generate `GoogleCredentials` object from access and private keys, but you can do that from credentials file as mentioned in the documentation.

I found [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gcs-hmac-signedurl-3166b995f237) article using the key pair to upload/download files but it's in python and I am unable to figure this out for `java`/`scala`.

Now my boss keeps saying that there IS a way to upload/download files using this key pair technique and he says he has done it in some previous project using `apache-spark`/`scala`. 
But I am unable to figure out how to do it.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176694/how-can-i-get-access-to-google-cloud-storage-using-an-access-and-a-secret-key/55178902#55178902) answer saying it is not possible to do that but there's that article where it is done in Python and a senior person saying he has done it.
As you can see from all the articles in question, you can see I did a lot of research on it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service account as an IAM entity with it own permissions set, and then create a key (json) so you can authenticate as that service account in your application, on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) you can learn more and there is even a Java snippet with an example

Comment: I already have the key pair, I am looking for way to use them.

Comment: Does this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) helps?

Comment: No Sir it does not, it is the same method which I used and works but I don't want to use. The credentials file method.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the method you tried before, I believe that if you want to use GCP buckets with the HMAC keys,  you need to follow the Amazon S3 standard way and once you have it working with s3 and you have generated the HMAC keys on GCP,  you have to use your code which already works with s3 and use a specific URL endpoint format to GCP bucket and objects and then just replace the HMAC GCP keys where you had your s3 keys [like this.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple) Hope this helps.